# how to make @IBAction in table?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, call

I wrote an application to have a table and when i press the button it would make a call. I have already done a table, code as follow..

```
var callContent = ["Police","Hospital"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return callContent.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Name")
    cell.textLabel?.text = callContent[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

and my call function

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://0812742111")!
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
```

Now i want to make an action from table to connect with my call function.
Can you guys make a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to implement `UITableViewDelegate`'s `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

[Here is the Apple documentation for that class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: After do it, it can make IBAction right? and do i need to insert button?

Comment: You do not need an IBAction. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called when you press on a table cell.

Comment: Do i need to have an if else to which one is pressed or no need? @ Oliver

Comment: `indexPath` will tell you which one is pressed, similar to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.